# How do I restore a destroyed widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

```py
def change_section_to_main():
    SUB_SECTION.destroy()
    APP_MAIN_FRAME.pack()
```

I want to restore the widget "APP_MAIN_FRAME". I thought I could do it with pack() turns out I was wrong. I keep getting this Error >>

```py
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame
```

Comment: Use `SUB_SECTION.pack_forget()` instead of `SUB_SECTION.destroy()`, assuming you used `.pack`

Comment: You need to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should use ```place - place_forget()``` or ```grid - grid_forget()``` or ```pack - pack_forget()```

Answer (score 1):

You can't "undestroy" a widget. Once it has been destroyed it can no longer be used.

Usually, the solution to this specific problem is to hide the widget rather than destroy it. You can hide it by using one of `pack_forget`, `grid_forget`, `grid_remove` or `place_forget` depending on exactly what you want to have happen and on which tool (`pack`, `grid`, or `place`) that you used to add it to the window.

If you expect to hide and show a widget often, `grid` is the best choice since `grid_remove` will remember how the item was placed. A subsequent call to `grid()` with no arguments will restore all of the settings. `pack` and `place` do not remember the configuration of a widget when it is forgotten.